# Variables configured in bashrc still been prompted to be exported

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I've the [this](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/blob/efd2819870ea5ae1a7a617f043b3fc6698ada22f/examples/project_template/gen_misc.sh) bash file that I need to export two variables SDK_PATH and BIN_PATH so to not worry exporting them anymore I added them in the `~/.bashrc` file but when I run the bash it prompts me that I still need to export the variables even though I'm able to echo them in the terminal. How do I make them to be exported automatically?

I declared the variables in the `~/.bashrc` file as follows:

```
SDK_PATH=~/SDKs/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK
BIN_PATH=./bin/
```

Comment: How did you define them in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Thank you heemayl for the quick reply, I added the declaration in the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `export` the variable definitions in `~/.bashrc` too, otherwise they won't be propagated to the child processes of the interactive shell session (that `source`-s the `~/.bashrc` file). Do:

```
export SDK_PATH=~/SDKs/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK
export BIN_PATH=./bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

Now add this two line

```
  export SDK_PATH
  export BIN_PATH
```

Comment: In `bash` it is cleaner to do it at the same time you're assigning the variable.  An `export` by itself would be needed for Bourne shell or other ancient shells.